# Creating a New DataFrame Column by Using a Comparison Operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like something similar to this:

```
    0
0   3
1  11
2   7
3  15
```

And I want to add a column using two comparison operators. Something like this:

```
df[1] = np.where(df[1]<= 10,1 & df[1]>10,0)
```

I want my return to look like this:

```
    0   1
0   3   1
1  11   0
2   7   1
3  15   0
```

But, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Should the `10,1` and `10,0` there be `10.1` and `10.0` instead? Because as it is, it looks like it's evaluating three things in the `where` and one of them is `1 & df[1] > 10`, which may be what's causing the type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 3, 1: 11, 2: 7, 3: 15}})
Out[1292]: 
    0
0   3
1  11
2   7
3  15
```

**Solution**

```
#compare df['0'] to 10 and convert the results to int and assign it to df['1']
df['1'] = (df['0']<10).astype(int)

df
Out[1287]: 
    0  1
0   3  1
1  11  0
2   7  1
3  15  0
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries. Please accept it as the answer if it's useful.